# How to run R Shiny App in Docker Container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, golem

I built a Docker Image for an R Shiny App and ran the corresponding container with Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home. When trying to open the App with my web browser, only the index is shown. I don't know why the app isn't executed.

The log shows me this:

```
*** warning - no files are being watched ***
[2019-08-12T15:34:42.688] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.12.1 (Node.js v10.15.3)
[2019-08-12T15:34:42.704] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2019-08-12T15:34:43.100] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
```

I already specified the app host-to-container path by executing the following command which refers to a docker hub image:

```
docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 -v /C/Docker/App/:/srv/shinyserver/ -v /C/Docker/shinylog:/var/log/shiny-server/  didsh123/ps_app:heatmap
```

My Docker File looks like the following:

```
# get shiny serves plus tidyverse packages image
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:latest

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev

##Install R packages that are required--> were already succesfull
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shinydashboard','shiny', 'plotly', 'dplyr', 'magrittr'))"

#Heatmap related packages
RUN R -e "install.packages('gpclib', type='source')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('rgeos', type='source')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('rgdal', type='source')"

# copy app to image
COPY ./App /srv/shiny-server/App

# add .conf file to image/container to preserve log file
COPY ./shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf


##When run image and create a container, this container will listen on port 3838
EXPOSE 3838

###Avoiding running as root --> run container as user instead
# allow permission
RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server
# execute in the following as user --> imortant to give permission before that step
USER shiny

##run app
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

So when I address the docker ip and the assessed port in the browser, the app should run there, but only the index is displayed. I use the following line:

```
http://192.168.99.100:3838/App/
```

I'm glad for every hint or advice. I'm new to Docker, so I'm also happy for detailed explanations.

Answer (score 10):

To use shiny with docker, I suggest you use the [golem](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem) package. golem provides a framework for builing shiny apps. If you have an app developed according to their framework, the function `golem::add_dockerfile()` can be used to create dockerfiles  automatically.

If you are not interested in a framework, You can still have a look at [the source for add_dockerfile()](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/blob/bf1ac442680f2041e456684b1e07c847006656c5/R/add_deploy_helpers.R#L139-L200) to see how they manage the deployment. Their strategy is to use `shiny::runApp()` with the port argument. Therefore, `shiny-server` is not necessary in this case.

The Dockerfile in golem looks roughly like this

```r
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.1
RUN R -e 'install.packages("shiny")'
COPY app.R /app.R
EXPOSE 3838
CMD R -e 'shiny::runApp("app.R", port = 3838, host = "0.0.0.0")'
```

This will make the app available on port `3838`. Of course, you will have to install any other R packages and system dependencies.

#### Additional tips

- To increase reproducibility, I would suggest you use `remotes::install_version()` instead of `install.packages()`.
- If you are going to deploy several applications with similar dependencies (for example `shinydashboard`), it makes sense to write your own base image that can be used in place of `rocker/tidyverse:3.6.1`. This way, your builds will be much quicker.

Answer (score 3):

## Minimal Reproducible Example

1. Create an empty directory (can be called anything you want)
2. Inside it, create two things:

   i. A file called `Dockerfile`

   ii. An empty directory called `app`
3. Place your shiny app inside the directory called `app`.

   - Your shiny app can be a single `app.R` file, or, for older shiny apps, `ui.R` and `server.R`. Either way is fine (see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/) for more on that).

- If unsure about any of the above, just copy the files found [here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/shiny-mre).

Place this in Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

COPY ./app/* /srv/shiny-server/

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

In the terminal, `cd` to the root of the empty directory you created in step 1, and build the image with

```sh
docker build -t shinyimage .
```

Run the container with

```sh
docker run -p 3838:3838 shinyimage
```

Finally, visit this url to see your shiny app: http://localhost:3838/

[Here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/shiny-mre#minimal-reproducible-example-of-a-shiny-app-in-docker)'s a copy of all of the above in case anything's unclear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs for any useful information? And exec into the container to verify if the App content is copied to the correct location.

Because the way /App content is copied looks incorrect

The content of `/App` is copied into the image to `/srv/shiny-server/App` during the build phase and you are trying to override `/srv/shiny-server` content using  -v option when running the container.

Looks like during runtime the App data copied is being overwritten.

Try without `-v /C/Docker/App/:/srv/shinyserver/` or use `-v /C/Docker/App/:/srv/shinyserver/App/`

`docker run --rm -p 3838:3838  -v /C/Docker/shinylog:/var/log/shiny-server/  didsh123/ps_app:heatmap`

Comment: Thank you for the advice concerning the /App content. I fixed this. But since I'm new to Docker, I did not work with log files yet. I attached the lines I received when executing the log command to my question above. Could you have a look at them, too? Furthermore, I executed the container as you suggested, it worked.

Comment: @Heysa12 Good to know it worked. Based on the logs the app is using the config file `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`, but when you are copying `COPY ./shiny-server.conf.txt /etc/shiny-server/` - `.txt` file is copied. That means your app is using default config instead of the file you copied into the image.

Comment: You can also add `USER appuser` to dockerfile to mitigate the security risk warning from the logs. Ref: https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b

Comment: The container is not running as root anymore, but as user instead (see edits in question). So this is fixed, but still the same issue. Could it have something to do with the config file? What would be the correct command inside the docker file to copy my own config file from the github repository to which it is related instead of the default one you mentioned?

Comment: @Heysa12 - Use this `COPY ./shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/`. Your are trying to copy a .txt file into /etc/shiny-server - check the file extension in the local directory.

Comment: Now I'm using a slightly adjusted file from a tutorial and also modified the Dockerfile as you suggested, but it seems like the COPY command doesn't work properly. I defined the shiny User inside the Dockerfile as well as in the config file, but as soon as I comment that line in the Dockerfile out, the log shows me the 'running as root' warning again. Do you have an idea here?